# "Как другие" обособляется?

Tags: пунктуация, как

"Я не люблю поступать как другие".
Обособляется ли здесь "как другие"?

На грамота.ру есть такое правило: *"Если оборот с союзом КАК входит в состав сказуемого и предложение без такого оборота не имеет законченного смысла, например: Она держится как хозяйка"*.

Относится ли данное предложение к правилу? Или здесь нужна запятая, так как "Я не люблю поступать, как (поступают) другие"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не обособляется, так как это сопоставление характеризует действие(не люблю термин «образ действия»).

Тропинка извивалась как змея.
Сербы сражались как львы.
Мечты рассеялись как дым.

Comment: Jim Korbett, вы хотя бы Розенталя почитали бы.  И ссылки прилагайте к вашим рассуждениям о ваших личных предпочтениямх:  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp147  пункт 4. Примечание. При анализе подобных примеров мы исходим из авторской пунктуации и пытаемся ее объяснить, что, как известно, является делом весьма сложным.

Comment: Так, сопоставляя приведенные выше предложения из стихотворений М. Ю. Лермонтова с его же фразой Она ускользнёт, как змея, порхнёт и умчится, как птичка, мы можем допустить, что в последнем случае автору важно было создать художественные образы путем чистого сравнения (подобно змее, подобно птичке, хотя сравнение сохраняется и в сочетаниях ускользнёт змеёй, умчится птичкой, но с добавочным оттенком образа действия)". Поэтому  русская речь - это не приложение к правилам, а напротив, правила - это наблюдение за речью, нахождение общих закономерностей и их обобщение.

Comment: Подобное предложение мы только что разбирали, оно имеет варианты. Подумайте, понаблюдайте за своей речью, в  Нацкорпус загляните.

Comment: Просто в вашем случае невозможна двоякая пунктуация. Вот два примера:    
Я не люблю лицемерить, как большинство.(Большинство людей лицемерит, но я не хочу поступать также)       
Я не люблю лицемерить как большинство.(Меня не устраивает техника лицемерия большинства, я куда более искусен в этом.)

В вашем предложении нельзя ставить запятую, так как предложение будет бессмысленным.
Я не люблю поступать как другие.(Я у мамки нонконформист)
Я не люблю поступать, как другие.(бессмысленное предложение)

Comment: Ничего невозможного нет, невозможность ―  это ошибочное состояние нашего сознания. Вот вам варианты из литературы, изучайте и делайте выводы. (1) Что же мне делать дальше? Буду поступать, как другие пассажиры. Они ждут, когда привезут чемоданы, ― я жду тоже. [Юлия Друнина.  (1968)] (2) Ему было известно, что во дворце прислуга ворует что хочет и ест что хочет; Халтурин должен был поступать как другие. [М. А. Алданов. Истоки.  (1942-1946)]  Представьте заданную ситуацию в двух вариантах, пофантазируйте. Вы же любите этим заниматься, так займитесь с пользой для дела.

Comment: (2) Халтурин должен был поступать как другие. Если поставить запятую, то предложение будет иметь смысл, только если использовать слово «поступать» в значении «поступать в университет».
Халтурин мог пойти работать, но он должен был поступать, как другие.

Comment: (1) Буду поступать как другие пассажиры — тоже ждать. Сочетание слов «буду поступать» — если брать слово «поступать» в значении «совершать поступок» — не имеет какого либо законченного смысла без сочетания «как другие пассажиры». «Поступать как другие пассажиры» — неразделимое словосочетание в данном предложении. Тут уважаемая Юлия Друнина допустила ошибку.

Comment: Ну да, ошиблись все, только вы безупречны. Вы когда-нибудь слушали свою речь или речь  других людей, обращали внимание, что расстановка ударений может быть разной. Это зависит от самого предложения, от контекста. Если ставим ударение на "поступать", то надо обособлять оборот, а если не ставим, то оборот попадает в позицию обстоятельства и не обособляется. Всё просто, не правда ли?

Comment: Но в предложении Друниной ударение падает на «как другие пассажиры». Это и есть более грамотно сформулированная причина не обособлять данное сочетание.

Вы поступаете как другие пассажиры? Нет, я буду, поступать как другие пассажиры. (ударение на «буду»)  Что вы будете делать как другие пассажиры? Я буду поступать, как другие пассажиры. (ударение на «поступать») Что вы собрались делать? Я буду поступать как другие пассажиры.(ударение на «как другие пассажиры»)

Comment: Вы сначала слушайте, а потом анализируйте. ЧтО же мне делать дальше? Буду поступАть, как другИе пассажиры. ОнИ ждут, когда привезут чемоданы, ― Я жду тоже.  Мы (Я и Юлия Друнина) говорим так.  Другой вариант здесь тоже возможен, но он отнюдь не отменяет этот вариант. Поэтому не надо настаиваить на своем единственном и только его считать  правильным. (Кстати, при обособлении оборота ударение падает и на глагол,  и на оборот.)